# Affine cipher does not satisfy the diffusion property.

Tags: cryptography

Generally, we know that substitution ciphers do not have the property of diffusion. And affine ciphers is the special case of substitution ciphers. But how can we prove that affine cipher does not satisfy the diffusion property?

Comment: It will depend on how you *define* diffusion formally. So please state how you define it.

Comment: Diffusion property says that one change character in plaintext should affect as many characters as possible in cipher text.